# Should I use a nested select or create a temporary table for this situation in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
                  EMPLOYEES
empno   firstname  lastname    reportsTo    designation
1002    Murphy     Diane            null    President
1056    Patterson  Mary             1002    VP Sales
1076    Firrelli   Jeff             1002    VP Marketing
1088    Patterson  William          1056    Sales Manager (APAC)
1102    Bondur     Gerard           1056    Sale Manager (EMEA)
1143    Bow        Anthony          1056    Sales Manager (NA)
```

This is the table I am dealing with ,here the **column `reportsTo` refers to `empno` of the boss**.

I don't know what to **query** to get **the name of the boss of the employee along with his name** as output in MySQL. What I need is something like:

```
firstname    lastname    assistant_of
Patterson    Mary        Murphy Diane
Firrelli     Jeff        Murphy Diane
Patterson    William     Patterson Mary
Bondur       Gerard      Patterson Mary
Bow          Anthony     Patterson Mary
```

What should I do go for a temporary table or can I do it using nested select.

This might question might seem similar to [Use Temporary Tables or Nested Select in retrieving data from multiple table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778295/use-temporary-tables-or-nested-select-in-retrieving-data-from-multiple-table)
but **"every query is a different story"**

Comment: If you are stuck, then you probably attempted some query.  You should edit your question with the query you are stuck on.  You should also decide which database you are using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Not exactly stuck sir it's that I don't know what to do to get my desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *self join*:

```
SELECT b.firstname,
       b.lastname,
       a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastname AS assisant_of
FROM   EMPLOYEES a
       JOIN EMPLOYEES b
         ON a.empno = b.reportsTo
```

Comment: Should be a left join, I believe.  Pretty sure just using Join implies inner join which would cause the president's record to be skipped over if it needed to be retrieved.

Comment: @user2366842 - president's record is not present in Expected output!!

Comment: Thanks I never had thought about the join thanks a lot

Comment: Good call.  didn't look at that very carefully.

Comment: @NoDisplayName yeah and it didn't come in the output either as expected.